# How to run openstack components' cli without SSL validation?

Tags: ssl, command-line-interface, openstack, nova, glance

(I use `IPv6_Address` instead of real IP address)

`.openrc` setting:

```
export OS_CLOUD=mycloud
export OS_USERNAME=myusername
export OS_PASSWORD=mypassword
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=myproject
export OS_AUTH_URL=https://[IPv6_Address]:5000/v3
```

If set this config in the `clouds.yml` file:

```
  mycloud:
    identity_api_version: "3"
    region_name: RegionOne
    verify: False
    auth:
      auth_url: https://[IPv6_Address]:5000/v3
      user_domain_name: "Default"
      project_name: "myproject"
      project_domain_name: "default"
```

Run `openstack server list` can work. But this time run `nova list` got

```
No handlers could be found for logger "keystoneauth.identity.generic.base"
ERROR (SSLError): SSL exception connecting to https://[IPv6_Address]:5000/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='IPv6_Address', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Try `nova list --insecure` got

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
usage: nova [--version] [--debug] [--os-cache] [--timings]
            [--os-region-name <region-name>] [--service-type <service-type>]
            [--service-name <service-name>]
            [--os-endpoint-type <endpoint-type>]
            [--os-compute-api-version <compute-api-ver>]
            [--os-endpoint-override <bypass-url>] [--insecure]
            [--os-cacert <ca-certificate>] [--os-cert <certificate>]
            [--os-key <key>] [--timeout <seconds>] [--collect-timing]
            [--os-auth-type <name>] [--os-auth-url OS_AUTH_URL]
            [--os-system-scope OS_SYSTEM_SCOPE] [--os-domain-id OS_DOMAIN_ID]
            [--os-domain-name OS_DOMAIN_NAME] [--os-project-id OS_PROJECT_ID]
            [--os-project-name OS_PROJECT_NAME]
            [--os-project-domain-id OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID]
            [--os-project-domain-name OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME]
            [--os-trust-id OS_TRUST_ID]
            [--os-default-domain-id OS_DEFAULT_DOMAIN_ID]
            [--os-default-domain-name OS_DEFAULT_DOMAIN_NAME]
            [--os-user-id OS_USER_ID] [--os-username OS_USERNAME]
            [--os-user-domain-id OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID]
            [--os-user-domain-name OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME]
            [--os-password OS_PASSWORD]
            <subcommand> ...
error: unrecognized arguments: --insecure
Try 'nova help ' for more information.
```

If don't have SSL certificate file local to connect to openstack https api, how to run `nova`, `glance` commands? Is there a `.novarc`, `.glancerc` config file to use them?

I also tried to create a `nova.rc` file with the same configuration as openrc then source it. But the same.

Answer (score 2):

To run nova with the '--insecure' option you have to be a bit more strict with the syntax.
`nova --insecure list` should work whereas
`nova list --insecure` should give the same errors that @rawmain has posted

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not familiar with your problem directly, OpenStack is trying to move its service clients to a unified one, which is the OpenStack client.

Here are some links regarding what I just mentioned (in the victoria version):

https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/victoria/

https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/victoria/cli/decoder.html

In this case and for the purpose of yours, you may enter the cli environment via "openstack --insecure"

https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/man/openstack.html